# Access my ubuntu terminal form other computer

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal, remote-access, remote-login

I having a Ubuntu 14.04 system in my office. I want to access the Terminal of my office system from home itself. I have enabled SSH and its is working fin with the local network connection in office campus. I need to access office pc from my home using Putty. My office network has a static IP. I want to login my Ubuntu system by entering the static IP followed by the user name in Putty. There are several Windows machines connected in the office network. Only my system is running Ubuntu and SSH is also configured only in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's working from your internal network and not from outside, the normal reason is that the incoming port for you machine (port 22 by default) is closed by a firewall. Which, by the way, is the expected thing.

You should contact your office/campus IT administrator and ask them to open the port for you. After that,

1. you must take seriously the security of your machine. Update as soon as possible when there are security updates available
2. Think about installing a configuring some "guard" daemon, like `fail2ban`.

Comment: I have activated port forwarding. Now I can able to access it using putty, after entering the password it is saying Access Denied. Even-though I entered the correct password, it is saying Access Denied. Do I need to do additional configurations for that ?